# Extracting strings in double quotes and base64 data after that

Tags: python, regex

I have this sample data

```
extdata = """Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="NBFC fg.pdf"
JVBERi0xLjcKJcKzx9gNCjEgM....."""
```

I want to extract filename and the pdf that is in base64 using regex
something like this with searchkey

```
re.findall('filename="?(.*?)"' ,extdata)
```

by this i am able to extract filename.
I have to extract both filename and pdf base64

Comment: `re.findall('filename="(.*?)"\s*([\s\S]+)' ,extdata)`

Comment: Thanks its helped just one more thing [\s\S]+ for multi line i don't want multi line.

Comment: Then use `.*` or `.+`